# Why is day/night/dusk/dawn not assigned correctly to intervals between sunrise/sunset/night/nightEND?

Tags: r

I want to assign day/night/dusk/dawn to times of detections from my telemetry data and followed the solutions suggested to this question on stackoverflow: [Adding information on day/dusk/night/dawn for tracking data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428441/adding-information-on-day-dusk-night-dawn-for-tracking-data-in-r)

This is my df with t_ being my date/time column (=time of detection) I want to assign day/night/dusk/dawn to:

```
str(data)

'data.frame':   843 obs. of  8 variables:
$ date             : Date, format: "2021-08-08" "2021-08-08" ...  
$ lat              : int  66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 ...  
$ lon              : int  -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 ... 
$ id               : int  56985 56985 56985 56985 56985 56985 56985    56985 56985 56985 ...  
$ t_               : POSIXct, format: "2021-08-08 01:00:00" "2021-08-08 23:00:00" ...  
$ Receiver.ID      : int  302371 302371 302371 302372 302372 302372 302377 302372 302372 302376 ...
$ Position.in.fjord: chr  "T1R1" "T1R1" "T1R1" "T1R3" ...  
$ row_num          : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I got the time for sunrise, sunset, night and nightEnd for each day of my study with `getSunlightTimes` (suncalc).

Because this study is conducted partly during summernight (24h daylight) in 66°N, no "night" or "nightEnd" is given until 07 Sept

```
str(sun)

'data.frame':   843 obs. of  8 variables:  
$ date    : Date, format:  "2021-08-08" "2021-08-08" ...  
$ lat     : int  66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 66 ...  
$ lon     : int  -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23 -23    ...  
$ sunrise : POSIXct, format: "2021-08-08 04:46:07" "2021-08-08 04:46:07" ...  
$ sunset  : POSIXct, format: "2021-08-08 22:31:48"    "2021-08-08 22:31:48" ... 
$ night   : POSIXct, format: NA NA ...  
$ nightEnd: POSIXct, format: NA NA ..  
$ row_num : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Creating a new df with a column containing day/night/dusk/dawn:

```
 daynight <-data %>%
  full_join(sun, by="row_num") %>%
  mutate(period= case_when(t_ %within% interval(sunset, night) ~ 'dusk',
                            t_ %within% interval(night, nightEnd) ~ 'night',
                            t_ %within% interval(nightEnd, sunrise) ~ 'dawn',
                            t_ %within% interval(sunrise, sunset) ~ 'day'))
```

Day, dusk and dawn are mostly assigned correctly to the date/time data from the detections. Mistakes occur close to the transition between intervals, i.e. when the time of detection (t_) is within one hour of the time when the next interval (sunrise, sunset,..) beginns.
For example with t_ is one detection:

```
        t_          /       sunrise       /        sunset       / period
2021-09-14 07:00:00 / 2021-09-14 06:50:36 / 2021-09-14 20:07:21 / dawn
```

"dawn" should be "day".

How can I assign day/night/dusk/dawn 100% correctly to my data?

Comment: I do not have enough knowledge of this package, but your dawn class is defined as `interval(NA,sunrise)`. This might be causing an issue, if interval does not handle NA in the way we expect. Consider defining night as the period of 1 second between 23:59:59, 00:00:00, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: It could also be a problem with the time zone, have you checked that the time zones are equal for all columns

Comment: lubridate::tz()`` can help you which time zone is used

Comment: I ran your code Bertil Baron to set my data in the same time zone. Unfortunately, this does not change the false allocation of day/night/(..) to date/times of the detections.

Comment: It seems that time intervals are only based on hours of sunrise/sunset/(..) and don't include the minutes, with an hour being defined as 07:01 - 08:00, 08:01 - 09:00;.. (see example in original post)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make sure all time zones are set the same with

```
data %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.POSIXct), ~lubridate::`tz<-`(.,value = "UTC"))
```

you can of course use what ever time zone you like